# Integration Test : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit4, junit5

I'm trying to run the Integration test case. However, I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap the proxied object."

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AddressControllerIntegrationTest {
    
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    
    @Autowired
    AddressController addresscontroller;
        
    @Test
    public void testValidateAddressReturnStatusOk() throws Exception {
        Argument argument = new Argument();
        argument.setCity("Plano, TX");
        argument.setCountry("United States");
        argument.setState(null);
        argument.setZipcode("75024");
        argument.setCounty(null);
        argument.setLocationResults(null);
    
        ResponseEntity<?> response = addresscontroller.validateAddress(argument);
        
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK));
        assertThat(response.getStatusCodeValue(), is(200));
        assertNotNull(response);
    }       
}
```

Below is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
    at org.springframework.test.util.AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject(AopTestUtils.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpringBootMockResolver.resolve(SpringBootMockResolver.java:35) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.resolve(MockUtil.java:118) ~[mockito-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.isMock(MockUtil.java:108) ~[mockito-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.mockito.internal.util.DefaultMockingDetails.isMock(DefaultMockingDetails.java:32) ~[mockito-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:106) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:81) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:63) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:441) ~[spring-test-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterEach(SpringExtension.java:141) ~[spring-test-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:253) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:268) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:252) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210) ~[.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/PropStoreDataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource.getTarget(JndiObjectTargetSource.java:147) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.test.util.AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject(AopTestUtils.java:90) ~[spring-test-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/PropStoreDataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:833) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lambda$lookup$0(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:92) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:105) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:114) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource.getTarget(JndiObjectTargetSource.java:140) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share the complete stacktrace. There should also be a stacktrace of the causing exception.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have added the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Which spring boot version and which junit version do you use?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Junit 5 and spring boot 2.4.0.

Comment: @SwetaSharma Did you resolve this issue in the mean time?

Comment: Same issue. SwetaSharma, @Gvg did you resolve it?